# Percent limit with remainder distribution on PHP

Tags: php, arrays, limit, distribution, percentage

There is a list of percentages. The sum of the numbers is 100.

```
$percent = [20.88, 14.93, 14.14, 13.29, 5.06, 4.43, 4.24, 4.22, 2.57, 2.51, 2.38, 2.18, 1.94, 1.80, 1.34, 1.21, 0.81, 0.63, 0.50, 0.48, 0.30, 0.16];
```

I need to limit the maximum number to a specific value, and distribute the remainder over the rest of the numbers. If possible, keeping the proportions of the remaining percentages.

Tried the following solution:

```
$limit = 8;

// Calculating the remainder of numbers exceeding $limit.
$rest = array_reduce($percent, function ($a, $b) use ($limit) {
    return $limit < $b ? $a += ($b - $limit) : $a;
});

// Number of numbers not exceeding $limit.
$small = array_reduce($percent, function ($a, $b) use ($limit) {
    return $limit > $b ? ++$a : $a;
});

// Percent calc with limit up to $limit and addition of the remainder ($rest / $small).
array_walk($percent, function(&$value) use ($limit, $rest, $small) {
    $value = $limit < $value ? min($value, $limit) : $value + ($rest / $small);
});

print_r($percent);
print(array_sum($percent)) . "\n";
```

This code works correctly:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 6.7955555555556
    [5] => 6.1655555555556
    [6] => 5.9755555555556
    [7] => 5.9555555555556
    [8] => 4.3055555555556
    [9] => 4.2455555555556
    [10] => 4.1155555555556
    [11] => 3.9155555555556
    [12] => 3.6755555555556
    [13] => 3.5355555555556
    [14] => 3.0755555555556
    [15] => 2.9455555555556
    [16] => 2.5455555555556
    [17] => 2.3655555555556
    [18] => 2.2355555555556
    [19] => 2.2155555555556
    [20] => 2.0355555555556
    [21] => 1.8955555555556
)
100
```

But if I change the variable `$limit` to the value `6`, the limit is exceeded due to the addition of the remainder:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 7.24
    [5] => 6.61
    [6] => 6.42
    [7] => 6.4
    [8] => 4.75
    [9] => 4.69
    [10] => 4.56
    [11] => 4.36
    [12] => 4.12
    [13] => 3.98
    [14] => 3.52
    [15] => 3.39
    [16] => 2.99
    [17] => 2.81
    [18] => 2.68
    [19] => 2.66
    [20] => 2.48
    [21] => 2.34
)
100
```

I can't find an algorithm.

Comment: The problem lies in your very definition; you have to consider that _"distribute the remainder evenly"_ might not be possible (as proven by your example with the limit of 6). You have to decide what exactly you want to do when such a distribution is not possible.

Comment: Indeed, evenly distribution was a bad idea. I will correct the post, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an iterative approch.

1. limit the maximum value
2. while the sum is not 100:

   1. compute the missing value for each item under the limit
   2. add this value to item under the limit, without exceeding this limit

Code: ([demo](https://3v4l.org/D3rEG))

```
$percent = [20.88, 14.93, 14.14, 13.29, 5.06, 4.43, 4.24, 4.22, 2.57, 2.51, 2.38, 2.18, 1.94, 1.80, 1.34, 1.21, 0.81, 0.63, 0.50, 0.48, 0.30, 0.16];

$limit = 6;

// check if a solution is possible
if ($limit * count($percent) < 100) die("Not possible");

// 1. limit the maximum value
$limited = array_map(fn($value) => min($value, $limit), $percent);
// 2. while the sum is not 100
while (($remain = 100 - array_sum($limited)) > 0) 
{
    // get the "non-full" values
    $filtered = array_filter($limited, fn($v) => $v < $limit);
    // get the value to add for each items
    $evenly   = $remain / count($filtered);
    // add the value (maximum as  possible)
    $limited  = array_map(fn($value) => min($value + $evenly, $limit), $limited);
}

print_r($limited);
print_r(array_sum($limited));
```

Output:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => 6
>     [1] => 6
>     [2] => 6
>     [3] => 6
>     [4] => 6
>     [5] => 6
>     [6] => 6
>     [7] => 6
>     [8] => 4.9407142857143
>     [9] => 4.8807142857143
>     [10] => 4.7507142857143
>     [11] => 4.5507142857143
>     [12] => 4.3107142857143
>     [13] => 4.1707142857143
>     [14] => 3.7107142857143
>     [15] => 3.5807142857143
>     [16] => 3.1807142857143
>     [17] => 3.0007142857143
>     [18] => 2.8707142857143
>     [19] => 2.8507142857143
>     [20] => 2.6707142857143
>     [21] => 2.5307142857143
> )
> 100
> ```

See [this demo](https://3v4l.org/Ms9Vt) for PHP version prior to 7.4.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Please look at the total percentage total provided "$limit = 20;" It turns out over 100 percent.

Comment: It was a typo (see [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67043915/revisions)). A `6` was hard-coded :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much :)